# Windows install folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, db2

I am having difficulty uninstalling DB2 from my Windows 7 machine. For some reason, the installer stops responding and doesn't even show up on the Task Manager.

I found this article on how to uninstall in such situations:

> https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21104569

In the section titled 'Using FORCE_UNINSTALL', they ask you to 'go to the Windows Installer directory for the OS on which you have DB2 installed on (such as `c:\Windows\Installer` or `c:\WinNT\Installer`)'

What is this by default in Windows 7? How can I confirm that a directory is my Windows Installer directory?

In the next step, they have given a list of products and their codes. How do I figure out what product I have installed?

Finally, if anyone knows a better way to uninstall, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `C:\Windows\Installer`

Look for the code in the folder. Sorting will help.

You might also want to try something like [Revo Unistaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) to forcibly uninstall the program.